# How to filter an outer array based on an inner array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json like this and I want to get all the areas that have almost one service that has the selected property equal to true.

```
{
   "areas": [
      {
         "name": "area 1",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 4",
               "selected": true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 2",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 4",
               "selected": false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 3",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 4",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The result must contains only the areas with only the services with the selected property equal to true and must be pointed out without mutating the original array.

With this code

```
const result = areas.filter(area =>
  services.some(srv => srv.selected == true)
);
```

I obtain all the areas, but inside these areas I have all the services (with selected true and with selected false).

This is what I want instead:

```
{
   "areas": [
      {
         "name": "area 1",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 4",
               "selected": true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 2",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 4",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid mutating the original object, `map` each `input.areas` item to turn it into an object with only truthy `selected`s in its `services`, then `filter` by whether the `services` property has any items in it:

```js
const transform = (input) => input.areas
  .map(({ name, services }) => ({
    name,
    services: services.filter(({ selected }) => selected)
  }))
  .filter(({ services }) => services.length);

const input = {
   "areas": [
      {
         "name": "area 1",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 4",
               "selected": true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 2",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 4",
               "selected": false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 3",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": false
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name": "area 4",
         "services": [
            {
               "label": "srv 1",
               "selected": true
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 2",
               "selected": false
            },
            {
               "label": "srv 3",
               "selected": true
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};
console.log(transform(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and take only the parts where `services` have some items after filtering.

```js
var data = { areas: [{ name: "area 1", services: [{ label: "srv 1", selected: true }, { label: "srv 2", selected: false }, { label: "srv 3", selected: false }, { label: "srv 4", selected: true }] }, { name: "area 2", services: [{ label: "srv 1", selected: false }, { label: "srv 2", selected: true }, { label: "srv 3", selected: false }, { label: "srv 4", selected: false }] }, { name: "area 3", services: [{ label: "srv 1", selected: false }, { label: "srv 2", selected: false }, { label: "srv 3", selected: false }] }, { name: "area 4", services: [{ label: "srv 1", selected: true }, { label: "srv 2", selected: false }, { label: "srv 3", selected: true }] }] },
    result = data.areas.reduce((r, o) => {
        var services = o.services.filter(({ selected }) => selected);
        if (services.length) r.push(Object.assign({}, o, { services }));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter twice

```js
const res = data.areas.filter(e => {
    e.services = e.services.filter(s => s.selected);
    return e.services.length;
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const data = {
    "areas": [
    {
        "name": "area 1",
        "services": [
            {
                "label": "srv 1",
                "selected": true
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 2",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 3",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 4",
                "selected": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "area 2",
        "services": [
            {
                "label": "srv 1",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 2",
                "selected": true
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 3",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 4",
                "selected": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "area 3",
        "services": [
            {
                "label": "srv 1",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 2",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 3",
                "selected": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "area 4",
        "services": [
            {
                "label": "srv 1",
                "selected": true
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 2",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "srv 3",
                "selected": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
</script>
```

Comment: This will mutate the original object, which is often undesirable (it's also probably best for a use of `filter` to be pure)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
obj.areas.filter(area =>
  area.services = area.services.filter(srv => srv.selected == true)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough, 
you could basically use a combination of  `Array#filter`.

```js
const filterBySelectedServices = list => list
  .map(area => Object.assign({}, area, {
    services: area.services.filter(service => service.selected),
  }))
  .filter(area => area.services.length);

const data = {
  "areas": [
    {
      "name": "area 1",
      "services": [
        {
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 4",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "area 2",
      "services": [
        {
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 4",
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "area 3",
      "services": [
        {
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "area 4",
      "services": [
        {
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

console.log('result', filterBySelectedServices(data.areas));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `filter` and take only those element where services have some items after filtering

```js
let data = {"areas": [{"name": "area 1","services": [{"label": "srv 1","selected": true},{"label": "srv 2","selected": false},{"label": "srv 3","selected": false},{"label": "srv 4","selected": true}]},{"name": "area 2","services": [{"label": "srv 1","selected": false},{"label": "srv 2","selected": true},{"label": "srv 3","selected": false},{"label": "srv 4","selected": false}]},{"name": "area 3","services": [{"label": "srv 1","selected": false},{"label": "srv 2","selected": false},{"label": "srv 3","selected": false}]},{"name": "area 4","services": [{"label": "srv 1","selected": true},{"label": "srv 2","selected": false},{"label": "srv 3","selected": true}]}]}

let final = data.areas.reduce((op, inp) => {
  let services = inp.services.filter( ({selected}) => selected )
  if(services.length) op.push({...inp, services})
  return op
},[])

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
const data = {
  "areas": [{
      "name": "area 1",
      "services": [{
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 4",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "area 2",
      "services": [{
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 4",
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "area 3",
      "services": [{
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "area 4",
      "services": [{
          "label": "srv 1",
          "selected": true
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 2",
          "selected": false
        },
        {
          "label": "srv 3",
          "selected": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const res = data.areas.map(x => {
  // Destructure the name and services from the current callback object
  const { name, services } = x;

  // Now filter the services object where the .selected property is set to true
  const filteredServices = services.filter(x => x.selected);
  
  if (filteredServices.length) {
    // Project your desired object
    return { name: name, services: filteredServices }
  }
})
// Also filter for empty services
.filter(x => x);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter inside the callback of a filter, like this:

```js
let data = {"areas": [{"name": "area 1", "services": [{"label": "srv 1", "selected": true}, {"label": "srv 2", "selected": false}, {"label": "srv 3", "selected": false}, {"label": "srv 4", "selected": true}]}, {"name": "area 2", "services": [{"label": "srv 1", "selected": false}, {"label": "srv 2", "selected": true}, {"label": "srv 3", "selected": false}, {"label": "srv 4", "selected": false}]}, {"name": "area 3", "services": [{"label": "srv 1", "selected": false}, {"label": "srv 2", "selected": false}, {"label": "srv 3", "selected": false}]}, {"name": "area 4", "services": [{"label": "srv 1", "selected": true}, {"label": "srv 2", "selected": false}, {"label": "srv 3", "selected": true}]}]};

const result = data.areas.filter(area => {
  // filter area services        
  let selectedServices = area.services.filter(service => {
    return service.selected;
  });

  // If the area has selected services
  if (selectedServices.length) {
    // Save the selected services to area.services
    area.services = selectedServices;
    return true;
  } else {
    // Do not select the area
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

However as pointed out by @CodeManiac this will mutate the original array, if you want to preserve it then use [reduce](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp): `data.areas.reduce()` instead of `data.areas.filter()`

Comment: This mutates original array, you can use map or reduce and filter combination instead

Comment: @CodeManiac yes but I don't recall that this was an issue for him? :)

Comment: Even though it's not a problem here, Just wanted to point out that It's not considered as good programming practice, you can read [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/the-state-of-immutability-169d2cd11310)

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to specify that I need to NOT mutate the original array.. I edit the original question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After the first filtration you have done, you can filter the services in each index as follows:

```
result.forEach((item)=>{
     item.services = item.services.filter((service)=>service.selected==true);
})
```